# How to save image to sqlite database selected from gallery or captured from camera to sqlite database

Tags: android

I want to store image to sqlite database using blob selected from gallery or captured from camera and get back thease images from database to display in listview or gridview.

Comment: Ugly way to store and retrieve blob type of image in database .. Store path of images in database.

Comment: Why ugly way??.......because it is qiute slower??

Comment: Yes, It is slower and make performance  down of your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to store image and retrieve image from sqlite database.

code to store it

```
   // Convert your bitmap to byte array

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

cv.put("IMAGE", bytes);
```

code to retrieve it

```
    // Use Cursor to retrieve the image

     byte[] bytes = cursor.getBlob(column_index);

     ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

     Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```